# Can I use an ANOVA to compare success rates (binary data) from different groups?

Tags: anova, binary-data

I am trying to compare the effectiveness of 12 heuristic procedures. Therefore I am calculating the percentage of the solutions which are correct (thus binary, correct or not). To do this, I compare the results of my exact procedure with the results of my heuristic procedure and I count how many times the heuristic procedure is exact (I'm using around 11000 problem instances). I then divide this counted number by the total amount of problem instances (11000) and this thus results in a certain percentage for each method: they are all in between 34-57.

I would really like to prove that 1 (or more) heuristic method(s) is doing significantly better than the others. Can I do this using an ANOVA?

Comment: Welcome to our site! I have tried to edit this question to make it and its title slightly clearer, feel free to revert my changes if you don't consider them to have been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have used an ANOVA on proportions, for example, when measuring the proportion of daily activity spent doing a particular activity(primate behavior). I did not have binary data, however, but had time in activity divided the total time observed on a particular day. As such, I had a proportions for each day and for each animal. Since the proportions were close to being normally distributed and variances did not differ substantially, I used an ANOVA.

In your case, it sounds like you have a binary response from which the mean is the proportion of successes. In this case, I would consider a logistic regression with a Bernoulli distribution. For this model, since you have a categorical predictor with 12 levels, you'll have to pick a level to be the reference catergory. All levels will be compared to the reference category.

In case I am reading your question wrong, can you post an example of what your data looks like?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I added some more information, I hope it helps. Do you think I could use these percentages as proportions?

Comment: Do you have several percentages for each procedure? If you only have one proportion for each, an ANOVA would not be possible. Also, 80 % is equivalent to a proportion of .80.

Comment: Yes I do have several percentages. However, these are the proportions per group of problem instances, which have different characteristics, and are harder/easier for all methods. E.g.:
Method[1] scores 80% in group 1, 60% in group 2 and 20% in group 3.
Method[2] scores 60% in group 1, 30% in group 2 and 10% in group 3. 
Method[3] scores 50% in group 1, 40% in group 2 and 25% in group 3.
I score Method[1] = (80% + 60% + 20%)/3 =  53.33%
Method[2] = (60% + 30% + 10%)/3 = 33.33%
Method[3] = (50% + 40% + 25%)/3 = 38.33%

Can I use ANOVA when those groups are not identical?